# Oracle APEX style APEX_ITEM Dynamic form elements

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I followed the instructions from [this post](https://apextips.blogspot.com/2015/05/building-dynamic-forms.html) on how to create dynamic items in APEX. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_item.htm#AEAPI192) is clear on how to create the item but I cannot figure out how to make the item look like native APEX items.

I have attempted copying different CSS classes that I can see attached to the native items, but for the life of me I cannot get my dynamically created form elements to look and act the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While not yet deprecated, APEX_ITEM is not being actively developed, and it may be deprecated in the future. The APEX team recommends the use of Interactive Grids instead of APEX_ITEM for new development as that will be the path forward.

Comment: Thanks @DanMcGhan, my intent is to create a survey builder tool for end-users to create their own surveys for others to fill out. APEX_ITEM has been perfect for this, I'll do some investigation on how I can best present an interactive grid to the end-user in a not so grid like format.

Comment: Tell me more about the surveys. Do you show all the questions and answers on one page or one question per page? What's the maximum number of answers per question? What types of answers are you working with (checkboxes, radio buttons, etc.)?

Comment: HI @DanMcGhan,
The basic functionality is the definition of a survey, the definition includes things like the question, response type (free text, drop-down, checkbox et.c) and the sequence of questions. The page display then loops over the survey definition and displays them all on one page. When the participant answers all the questions and hits submits the process loops over all answered questions and saves them in the answers table in a key value pair approach. APEX_ITEM has been super useful for this to dynamically display survey fields.

Comment: I see. Yes, this is a use case where the flexibility of APEX_ITEM shines. I don't see IG working for this use case. I'll take your feedback to the team so they are aware. For now, Salim's answer is your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Chrome Browser, then the easiest way to get all the styles is to use the browser Copy styles.

Right click on an item created natively and select **Inspect**.
Right click on the selected HTML element under Elements tab and go to **Copy => Copy styles**

This will get you the styles associated with the native item. Now assign those styles to your dynamically generated item.

You need to do this for every item type.

Best Regards,
Salim

Comment: Perfect, a little extra work but I have been able to attach all the HTML/CSS around the form objects and they are behaving just like native form elements to the end-user. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Hi – just to add to Dan’s and Salim’s comments and recommendations. I agree that for this particular use case, APEX_ITEM work well. However, as Dan pointed out, the APEX_ITEM API is considered legacy code. While we may never actually remove this API from APEX, as this would break too many apps, we do not plan on developing this API further. There are many reasons, but really comes down to the APEX_ITEM API using its own code to render page items, and all new components, including standard form items and Interactive Grid form items, share the same, more modern implementation, which is fully integrated with the Universal Theme and accessible. There are also significant differences in the way form items are submitted to the server and the way this data is processed. We’re working towards providing better alternatives to the APEX_ITEM in the future.
- Marc

Comment: Hi Marc, Thank you for your contribution. However, this should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/comment).

Comment: @PeterPesch: That’s true, since this is commentary. Despite that, though, it still provides authoritative insight into a topic of core relevance to this question, and likely provides value to future readers.

Comment: Thank you for further insight Marc, much appreciated!

Comment: Since over three years, there is still no progress...

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
with
    TP_ORDEM_SERV_REC as (
        select  C.ID_FUNCAO,
                C.QT_EXEC
        from    TB_ORDEM_SERV_REC C
        where   C.ID_ORDEM_SERV = :P922_ID_ORDEM_SERV
        and     C.NUM_TAR = :P922_NUM_TAR) 
        
select  A.DESC_SUPLEMENT FUNCAO,
        '<div class="t-Form-fieldContainer t-Form-fieldContainer--floatingLabel lto'||A.ID_SUPLEMENT||' apex-item-wrapper apex-item-wrapper--text-field" id="it_'||A.ID_SUPLEMENT||'_CONTAINER">'||
            '<div class="t-Form-labelContainer">'||
                '<label for="it_'||A.ID_SUPLEMENT||'" id="it_'||A.ID_SUPLEMENT||'_LABEL" class="t-Form-label">Quant. Exec.</label>'||
            '</div>'||
            '<div class="t-Form-inputContainer">'||
                '<div class="t-Form-itemWrapper">'||
                    '<input type="hidden" name="f01" value="'||A.ID_SUPLEMENT||'"  />'||
                    '<input type="text" name="f02" id="it_'||A.ID_SUPLEMENT||'"  class="text_field apex-item-text" value="'||A.QT_EXEC||'" size="1" maxlength="2">'||
                '</div>'||
                '<span id="it_'||A.ID_SUPLEMENT||'_error_placeholder" class="a-Form-error" data-template-id="'||A.ID_SUPLEMENT||'_ET"></span>'||
            '</div>'||
        '</div>' QT_EXEC
from    TB_SUPLEMENT A,
        TB_USUARIO B,
        TP_ORDEM_SERV_REC C
where   A.FLAG_CTRL = 15
and     B.ID_OFICINA = :P922_ID_OFICINA
and     A.ID_SUPLEMENT = B.ID_FUNCAO
and     B.ID_FUNCAO = C.ID_FUNCAO (+)
group by A.DESC_SUPLEMENT,A.ID_SUPLEMENT,C.QT_EXEC
```

Then, just use `apex_application.g_f` to manipulate the result in the process as normal.