# Apex : How to run javascript from PL/SQL validation?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I'm running Apex 19.2

I have a page with a validation.

I would like to run Javascript from PL/SQL when my page validation fails.

In my validatin pl/sql function, I tried :

```
HTP.p ('<script type="text/javascript">');
HTP.p ('alert("coucou");');
HTP.p ('</script>');
```

but it's not working. Javascript is not running and nothing happens.

Doesn anyone know how to trigger some javascript when validation fails please ?

Thanks.
Cheers,

Comment: JavaScript must be part of the page when it is first loaded; you can't add it dynamically later. If you want an alert message, there are ways to handle that within APEX itself. Have you tried apex.server.process? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71588_01/AEAPI/apex-server-namespace.htm#AEAPI30050

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I can't use Apex.server.process because I need access to apex_application.g_f0n arrays (which are not populated before submitting the page) What I need is to run some javascript when validation fails. Do you know any event I can handle to achieve that please ?

Comment: That is not the way the validations work in apex. A validation is happening on page submit - at that point you can no longer access the UI. You could write some custom pseudo validation before submit using a dynamic action. As part of the dynamic action you can also execute javascript.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I see this is related to your previous question. Would you like me to put together an example for you?

Comment: @DanMcGhan I'd love to. Yes please :)

Comment: Hi Thomas, I updated my previous answer with an example. It's complex, but that's what it takes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61741878/apex-how-to-display-an-error-on-a-page-item-created-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to achieve something similar, but there is a side effect.

1. Create a hidden item, like P1_VALIDATION_FAILED. Set it to NULL while submitting the page. Check [apex.page.submit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aexjs/apex.page.html#.submit)
2. Convert your validation into "PL/SQL Function Body (Returning Boolean)". When validation fails, before RETURN FALSE statement, set P1_VALIDATION_FAILED value to Y.
3. Create a "Dynamic Action" (D.A.) which will fire on page load with server side PL/SQL condition as :P1_VALIDATION_FAILED = 'Y'. In this D.A. you can write your JS code.
4. You need to do another change for this to work. Go to "Page properties -> Advanced -> Reload on Submit" and set it to "Always". i.e. your page will be reloaded even when validation errors occurred. So, all D.A. which are suppose to fire on page load will be fired when validation errors occurred as-well. You can handle this with another hidden item, like P1_SUBMIT_STATE. You can set value of P1_SUBMIT_STATE to Y when page is submitted and you can set P1_SUBMIT_STATE to NULL at the end of page processing. You can use this hidden item for "actual" page load D.A. to fire conditionally.